# VBA function to select item from dropdown list on a webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to open up a page that automatically navgiates to a dropdown item. Basically this dropdown item is like a builtin bookmark on the webpage. I want it to load/open up ON this page. Nothing is working, it just opens the regular website. I do NOT know how to make it select a value from the dropdown. I want it to select the "Exposure By Region" dropdown. This is my code so far:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim URL As String

    Dim bookMark As Object

    URL = "http://mywebpagelink"

    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink URL

    ie.navigate (URL)

    Set webpage = ie.document

    Set bookMark = webpage.getElementByTagName("select").Click

    bookMark.Selected = True

End Sub
```

This is what the developer tools code is for that particular dropdown list:

```
<html>
..
<select>

<option value="Document\BMO_568">Default</option>

<option value="Server\BM1O89-65">Exposure by Region</option>

</select>
..
</html>
```

Anything would help at this point. Because currently it just opens up the webpage but not at the bookmark (dropdown value) that I want it to open up in.

Comment: There is no such thing as `getElementByTagName` - You probably want `getElementsByTagName` (see how it's plural?) - because tag names are not unique on a webpage. Knowing that, you will then get an array of tag names that you need to then parse to find the one you want.

Comment: so would I use getElementsByTagName("option")(1)..? how will it find the option tag name if it is within the select tag?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658315/vba-code-to-select-from-an-html-drop-down-using-value-rather-than-index

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: what is .Focus?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp

Comment: is 'op' in the above example supposed to be set as an object?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following macro. If that doesn't work, we need more information about the html code or better you tell us the url:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

  Dim url As String
  Dim browser As Object
  Dim nodeSelect As Object

  url = "http://mywebpagelink"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

  'Create node collection of al HTML elements with the tag name "select"
  Set nodeSelect = browser.document.getElementsByTagName("select")

  'If the needed dropdown is not the first one in the HTML
  'code, you must set the right index instead of 0
  nodeSelect(0).selectedIndex = 1

  'It is likely that the change to the page must be communicated
  'via an HTML event. This is probably the change event
   Call TriggerEvent(browser.document, nodeSelect(0), "change")
End Sub


Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```